# React, return boolean value from custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook that calculates the height and width of the page, this one:

```
const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
  height: 0,
  width: 0
});

useEffect(() => {
  const handleResize = () => {
    setWindowSize({
      height: window.innerHeight,
      width: window.innerWidth
    });
  };
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  handleResize();
  return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
}, []);

return windowSize;
```

Then, in different components, I'm deciding when the page is "mobile" or not with this:

```
const isMobile: boolean = (useWindowSize().width <= 768);
```

Then in my `return` function, I use that `isMobile` boolean value for render something or not.

My question is, how could I hace that custom hook, in order to return `isMobile` value just by calling it, in other words, I would like to have something like:

```
const isMobile: boolean = useIsMobile();
```

Comment: `const useIsMobile = () => useWindowSize().width <= 768`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra property in the state object:

```
const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
  height: 0,
  width: 0,
  isMobile: false
});
```

And set it like:

```
setWindowSize({
  height: window.innerHeight,
  width: window.innerWidth,
  isMobile: window.innerWidth <= 768
});
```

**Usage:**

```
const {isMobile} = useWindowSize();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create another custom hook. Something simple like:

```
const useIsMobile = (width = 768) => useWindowSize().width <= width;
```

Usage:

```
const isMobile = useIsMobile();
```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-return-boolean-value-from-custom-hook]